# What are the "aa." tags?

Tags: support, tagging

What do they mean and what purpose do they serve?

Comment: For example? Which ones?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're tags that are used on MathOverflow. The reason they were adopted there is that professional mathematicians are already familiar with the [two letter arXiv codes](http://arxiv.org/archive/math) for various areas of mathematics.

I don't think it makes sense to have these tags on math.SE. That is, I think [pr.probability] should just be changed to [probability]. A moderator can do this easily, so there's no need to go on a retagging spree.

Comment: Ah. I've never even heard of arXiv before. It seems redundant - the textual tags are more accessible and less confusing. Especially for people like me, who are interested in mathematics (it's considered a supporting discipline for my field) but aren't and probably will never be experts.

Comment: Would you take a look at Larry Wang's comment on [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57931/area51-se-2-0-site-specific-script-support-such-as-latex-in-beta-phase) and give us a heads up [over here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2/tex-math-markup-is-sorely-needed) about what we can expect for TeX support?

Comment: @Thomas: I completely agree. Since the target audience of math.SE isn't familiar with the arXiv, the two letter codes are just confusing. @Tom: done and done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a carry over from [Math Overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions).

However, it seems as though it is an impossible-to-enforce convention here.

Comment: *impossible-to-enforce convention*: because relatively few people think it is worthwhile, or even well-specified for this site.